# What is the standard approach to checking an Android Play Store in app purchase has been cancelled?

Tags: android, google-play

My app uses an in-app purchase to enable a 'pro' version, through the Android BillingClient library. This makes it painless to get pricing details, accept payment and mark the upgrade as purchased.

However, if I go into the console as the app owner and refund a purchase, I can't figure out how I am supposed to disable the pro features in my app. There doesn't seem to be anything in the `getPurchasesList()` result that indicates the status of the purchase, but also as far as I can tell this is cached on the local device so it isn't updated automatically.

Currently my check looks like this:

```
Purchase.PurchasesResult purchases = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        if (purchases != null)
        {
            List<Purchase> bought = purchases.getPurchasesList();
            if ( bought != null && 0 < bought.size() )
            {
                for (int i=0;i<bought.size(); i++)
                {
                    if ( bought.get(i).getSku().equals(PRO_VERSION) )
                    {
                        purchased = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there something I can do here to check whether the purchase has been refunded or a way to make a secondary background check later? I don't want to routinely remove the purchase notification from the cache because the app is likely to be used in areas of limited or patchy signal and I don't want anyone who has legitimately purchased it to suddenly lose their 'pro' version at a time they need it. At the same time if someone has purchased it and then been refunded, I would like to be able to reflect that in the app.

I am not currently running any back-end infrastructure of my own and I would prefer to keep it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there actually is no real solution to your problem. But after going through some Google articles it actually seems that in-app purchases are not intended to be refunded, except in some very rare edge-cases. This would mean refund-behavior is not intended as far as I can tell.

Source: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/113

Answer (score 1):

If an item has been refunded, it should not appear in the list returned by `getPurchasesList()`. Therefore, you could save the status of the purchase in the shared preferences:

```
Purchase.PurchasesResult purchases = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
    if (purchases != null)
    {
        preferences.setPro(false);
        List<Purchase> bought = purchases.getPurchasesList();
        if ( bought != null && 0 < bought.size() )
        {
            for (int i=0;i<bought.size(); i++)
            {
                if ( bought.get(i).getSku().equals(PRO_VERSION) )
                {
                    preferences.setPro(true);
                    purchased = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what I thought but I am definitely seeing a refunded purchase coming through on my test set-up. I have raised a bug with the team responsible so this may be down to a bug that needs fixing.

Comment: @glenatron Did you check "revoke" when you refunded an order?

Comment: I can confirm that queryPurchases() no longer returns a purchase within 4 hours after it is refunded and the product is revoked though queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() still returns the purchase record.